# How to link addresses within your site to a search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I have 6 different Coffee types on my dashboard, each with their own unique page address. If I search the coffee name, I would like it to take me to the details of that specific coffee type, i.e. its unique url after I submit a search.

Here is the snippet for the search bar:

```
<div class = "search">
        <form action = "/action_page.php">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
            <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a switch statement and then use it in the button "submit" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. One option would be to write a small function as an event listener to all changes happening in the search bar and shows matching results accordingly. After the use selects that option, you can have it as a `<a>` tag that will direct to the unique link you want. This can be either hardcoded or dynamic using JSON

Comment: could you provide a simple example of the listening function and use of the <a> tag?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out with some help. If there already exists a button event to go into each specific item, one can simply use the existing click event as an action.

1st bit of additional code: (found in a service.ts file)

```
selectedCoffee = new BehaviorSubject<Coffee>(null);

setCoffee(name: string){
    let coffee = COFFEES.find(coffee => coffee.name === name);    
    this.selectedCoffee.next(coffee);
  }
```

2nd bit added: (found in app.component)

```
constructor(private coffeeService: CoffeeService){} 

  searchInput: string;

search(){
    this.coffeeService.setCoffee(this.searchInput);
  }
```

One needs to import Coffee from a .ts file created...

3rd bit added: (found in app.component.html)

```
<div class = "search" id = "{{coffee.name}}">
        <form autocomplete = "off" action = "/action_page.php" class = "form-inline"> 
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control typeahead border-success" name="searchBar" placeholder = "Search here..." [(ngModel)]="searchInput">
            <button class = "btn btn-outline-success mx-2" (click)="search()">Search</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

4th bit added: (found in dashboard.component)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.coffeeService.selectedCoffee.subscribe(coffee => this.goToCoffee(coffee));
  }

goToCoffee(coffee: Coffee){    
    if(coffee){
      let view = document.getElementById(coffee.name);      
      if(view){
        view.click();
      }
    }
  }
```

Final bit added: (found in dashboard.component.html)

```
<h1 align = "center">The Coffees</h1>

<div class = "grid grid-pad">
 <div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
   <a *ngFor = "let coffee of coffees" class = "col-4" routerLink = "/detail/{{coffee.name}}">
    <div class = "module coffee d-flex justify-content-center mx-2" id="{{coffee.name}}">
      <h4 align = "center">{{coffee.name}}</h4>
    </div>
   </a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The id = "{{coffee.name}}" is the essential piece to calling all the preceding functions.